# Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Enterprise - Cross-Database Transactions

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions

I need to know if cross-database transactions are supported or not in Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Enterprise.

The wording on the following article is contradictory:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366279.aspx

> **Cross-database transactions within the same SQL Server instance are
>   not supported for Always On Availability Groups**. This means that no
>   two databases in a cross-database transaction may be hosted by the
>   same SQL Server instance. **This is true even if those databases are
>   part of the same Availability Group.**

This is then followed by the following statement:

> Cross-database transactions are not supported for database mirroring
>   or for Always On Availability Groups in any version of SQL Server
>   **prior to SQL Server 2016**.

Can someone please tell me which it is?

Supported or NOT supported?

Comment: `for database mirroring`. the two statements aren't contradictory. the second one is talking about something else.

Comment: for database mirroring *or* for Always On Availability Groups